# google auto complete results fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using a standard google autocomplete function that is not working. I must be passing the wrong value to it somewhere. When I enter a character, the autocomplete fires and it removes the datalist (locationAddressList) meant for the results and and the input field (locationAddress) out of the DOM.

html

```
        <section>Address<input id="locationAddress" class="address" type="text" list="locationAddressList" onkeyup="getGoogleAddresses('locationAddress');" />
        <datalist id="locationAddressList" style="font-size:12px"></datalist>
        </section>
```

Here's the function call:

```
function getGoogleAddresses(ID) {
var addressInput = "#" + ID;
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($(addressInput)[0], options);
var places = $(addressInput).load(autocomplete);
//places = places.slice(0, -15);
$(addressInput + "List").append(places);
```

Comment: What is `$(addressInput).load(autocomplete);`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Why are you calling `$(addressInput).load(autocomplete);`?  [That is causing your problem (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/275z5rgq/)

Comment: I thought addressInput was supposed to refer to the input field ID that I passed to the function. What should I call instead?

Comment: The only thing that I can see different in your fiddle example is that you commented out var places = $(addressInput).load(autocomplete); When I commented it out, the input field no longer disappears but the datalist gets  no results.

Comment: I copied and pasted your fiddle code and it bombs on $(addressInput + "List").append(places) because the part where the places value is set is commented out in your code, so I have no idea how or why your example actually works, but it does on your fiddle page.

Comment: Do you have some HTML in your page that you didn't post that matches that query?

Comment: Your first answer was right, but I couldn't understand what you meant. In "var places = $(addressInput).load(autocomplete);" addressInput is referencing the input field when it needs to reference the datalist id associated with the input field. Changed that and the input field no longer disappears and I think I get results back but they are not displaying in the datalist

Comment: What do you expect that line to do and why?

Comment: I expect it to load the autocomplete results into the places variable, and places appends results to the datalist that I specified. I really don't understand autocomplete very well, I am grabbing my code right from google documentation. The thing I've changed is I added an ID parameter to the function call.

Comment: Why do you expect jquery to know what do do with a google.maps.Autocomplete object?  The [jquery `.load()` method expects a URL](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I don't expect it to. I got the code from somewhere on the google site, and I used it with the load event as you see because that was in what I copied and pasted, and it has always worked. Transferred the code to this new page and it doesn't work. So for some reason, that .load does not fail at all on the first page I put it on.

Comment: It turns out that for some reason google places autocomplete does not work on an input field inside of an absolutely positioned section with a z-index applied. I remove those attributes and the field works fine.